# MySQL Import from CSV to Table: Empty Items are Handled Incorrectly

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I'm trying to import a csv file with some 86,000 fields into a MySQL table using the Table Data Import Wizard function in MySQL Workbench. The table fields are named after the rows in the .csv file and the table definition is:

```
CREATE TABLE `spy_eod_202201` (
  `[QUOTE_UNIXTIME]` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `[QUOTE_READTIME]` text,
  `[QUOTE_DATE]` text,
  `[QUOTE_TIME_HOURS]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[UNDERLYING_LAST]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[EXPIRE_DATE]` text,
  `[EXPIRE_UNIX]` int DEFAULT NULL,
  `[DTE]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[C_DELTA]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[C_GAMMA]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[C_VEGA]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[C_THETA]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[C_RHO]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[C_IV]` text,
  `[C_VOLUME]` text,
  `[C_LAST]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[C_SIZE]` text,
  `[C_BID]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[C_ASK]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[STRIKE]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_BID]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_ASK]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_SIZE]` text,
  `[P_LAST]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_DELTA]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_GAMMA]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_VEGA]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_THETA]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_RHO]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_IV]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[P_VOLUME]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[STRIKE_DISTANCE]` double DEFAULT NULL,
  `[STRIKE_DISTANCE_PCT]` double DEFAULT NULL
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci
```

And the csv file starts with:

```
[QUOTE_UNIXTIME], [QUOTE_READTIME], [QUOTE_DATE], [QUOTE_TIME_HOURS], [UNDERLYING_LAST], [EXPIRE_DATE], [EXPIRE_UNIX], [DTE], [C_DELTA], [C_GAMMA], [C_VEGA], [C_THETA], [C_RHO], [C_IV], [C_VOLUME], [C_LAST], [C_SIZE], [C_BID], [C_ASK], [STRIKE], [P_BID], [P_ASK], [P_SIZE], [P_LAST], [P_DELTA], [P_GAMMA], [P_VEGA], [P_THETA], [P_RHO], [P_IV], [P_VOLUME], [STRIKE_DISTANCE], [STRIKE_DISTANCE_PCT]
1641243600, 2022-01-03 16:00,2022-01-03,16,477.77,2022-01-03,1641243600,0,1,0,0,0,0, , ,0, 2 x 1,242.16,243.3,235,0,0.01, 0 x 2471,0.01,-0.0003,-0.00003,0.00049,-0.00488,0,4.60994,0,242.8,0.508
1641243600, 2022-01-03 16:00,2022-01-03,16,477.77,2022-01-03,1641243600,0,1,0,0,0,0, , ,0, 1 x 1,237.16,238.3,240,0,0.01, 0 x 2337,0.01,-0.00042,0.00004,0.00011,-0.0051,0,4.47957,0,237.8,0.498
1641243600, 2022-01-03 16:00,2022-01-03,16,477.77,2022-01-03,1641243600,0,1,0,0,0,0, , ,0, 1 x 1,232.16,233.3,245,0,0.01, 0 x 2327,0.01,-0.00036,0,0.00028,-0.00498,0,4.35078,0,232.8,0.487
```

The import isn't quite working though. MySQL returns a 1206 error for rows where `[P_VOLUME]` is empty. Even more strangely, whenever a row fails to be imported the row number is always reported as 1.

What am I doing wrong? How do I tweak MySQL to prop up the import wizard's wizardry?

Thanks in advance,

**Update**

Now I've adopted the monumentally cack-handed approach of importing everything as nullable text fields. Next I will try to update the field types.

Unfortunately the csv files are too large and take very long to load, so I can't easily test different table and import-code configurations.

Comment: the [] are not good for mysql but even then must you have fixed rules to import the data, as we don't have the original csv, it is hard to tell which settings work, so you need to try them all out

Comment: Have you tried using LOAD DATA INFILE instead of the wizard?

Comment: Make sure what when P_VOLUMN is empty there are two TAB delimiters in the file.

Comment: @nbk, Indeed it's unwieldy, but the backquotes took care of this issue. I'm using the same field names as in the CSV initially. The plan is to change them after the import is working correctly.

Comment: @barmar I did. Same result. :-(

Comment: Did what? Use `LOAD DATA INFILE` or ensure that there are delimiters around the empty field?

Comment: You may use input preprocessing: ```LOAD DATA .. (.. , @variable, ..) SET `column` = CASE WHEN TRIM(@variable) = '' THEN [NULL | DEFAULT] ELSE @variable END, ..```. You may load separate lines into temptable then parse them with another query. There are more variants, but they are even more complex.

Comment: @barmar. Both. The empty fields have a space. At least on inspection it seems the file is sound.

Comment: So it's <tab><space><tab>?

Comment: <comma><space><comma>